# Was there a Jedi academy on a jungle planet?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, the-force

In **Star Wars: Force and Destiny Core Rulebook** and **Star Wars: Force and Destiny Game Master's Screen**, both by [Fantasy Flight Games](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/), there are images of a building with Jedi younglings practicing lightsaber duels and telekinesis in front of it.

[image]

Now, are these merely illustrations for the books, or is there a story for this location and its people? Who is the gray-haired Jedi Master instructing the younglings? Is this a Jedi academy on some jungle planet, and did it actually take place on the official (Legends) storyline? And on which period of time?

Comment: *Not* the [Dawn Temple](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dawn_Temple), at least. It’s too forested.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the Jedi Academy in Jedi Knight II was on a jungle planet.

Comment: @Helmar: That's on Yavin IV (near the rebel base from A New Hope). It was supposed to be a very old Jedi or Sith temple that Luke converted to a new Jedi Temple after Return of the Jedi. But I don't know if that picture is supposed to be the same temple. Doesn't really look like it. More info [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Temple_(Yavin_4)).

Comment: What is a "jungle planet"? Is the earth a jungle planet?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is no such planet that both contained a Jedi Temple, a jungle, and a building of that sort of architecture. In fact, I cannot recall seeing anything that looks like that building shown in the picture. Hence, I must come to the conclusion that this is merely the work of an artist, and not anything in actual canon. As for the grey-haired Jedi Master, the only person I could think of off the top of my head would be the Dark Woman (seeing as she had grey hair, but I'm only thinking of her because of your description of grey hair). You can read more on her [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/An%27ya_Kuro).

As for a planet that is similar to the one shown above would be the Jedi Temple established on Yavin IV in the remains of an old Massassi Temple (The same one used by the Rebellion to plan their attack on the Death Star in Episode IV, if I remember correctly) when Luke Skywalker reformed the Jedi Order. You can read more about the [planet](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Yavin_4/Legends), the [temple](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Great_Temple_(Yavin_4)), and the [praxeum](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jedi_Praxeum) by following these links.

Hope I was helpful.